# User Prompt Code using Multi-Dimensional arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I am writing a C program that will allow the user to choose what type of data to program via the console. Let's say I have 2 arrays with some data:

```
unsigned short A1[ ] = 

{

0x0001, 0x0403, 0x6014, 0x0900, 0x0080, 0x0008, 0x0000, 0x12A0,

0x28B2, 0x1ADA, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0056,


};

unsigned short A2[ ] = 

{

0x0001, 0x92C7, 0x356A, 0x0154, 0x3100, 0x744A, 0x6761, 0x5D53,

0x3274, 0x434E, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x4400, 0x6769, 0x6C69

};
```

How should I go about coding this? I would like this to be a user prompt type of program, where it grabs the array upon enter A1 or A2. Do I use getline()? As in, do fprint("Choose Array to program: "); and then what?

Answer (score 0):

```
int input;

printf("Please input an integer value: ");
scanf("%d", &input);
```

This will only allow integer values to be entered but you can adapt to fit your needs.  Obviously additional logic will need to follow to create the appropriate array.